# Can we make a complete server side app using cross platform like titanium and phonegap

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

I want to make a app for iOS and Android and i want that app should be cross platform.The basic purpose of email is like social sites mean  if any body uses in company he can see all the catalogs of videos and audio and also record audio video from the app so is it possible to make using java script for cross platform or i have to make different for all iOS and Android

Comment: use PhoneGap http://phonegap.com/

Comment: @PavelKatunin will all the functionality which i have mentioned easy with phonegap and you have downvoted my question or anyother

Comment: why do you think that I have downvoted your question? :) phonegap can help you in some functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-platform frameworks such as Titanium or Phonegap/Cordova can help you build a cross-platform application for iOS and Android using only JavaScript.

However the use of native features such as the Camera, is not the easiest thing to use, it is not implemented in all the frameworks and not for all the mobile operating systems.

But in your case, Titanium or Phonegap should be able to handle the features you need for Android and iOS, plus if a feature is not implemented yet, you can still use or write a native plugin for the framework, that would give you more flexibility.

Comment: so if i make cross plate form app how to differentiatle like android has more device how we will adjust css and other things for this

Comment: You can handle the device screen size with a responsive approach (using CSS3 media queries) if that's what you're asking.

Comment: can you please share some things regrading responsive approach

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: Notice that it would only work in a framework that uses HTML/CSS layout for the user interface. Phonegap is based on HTML but Titanium is not, you can still use it but it's not the philosophy of this framework.